# I am making a small clock in c++, but ran into a "bug" or somethig

Tags: c++

Hope you get what I'm trying to make,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int q = 1;

    int s = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int h = 0;

    while (int q = 1) {

        s = s + 1;

        if (s = 60) {
            m = m + 1;
            s = 0;
        }

        if (m = 60) {
            h = h + 1;
            m = 0;
        }

        cout << h << ":" << m << ":" << s << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this it goes like;

`1:0:0
2:0:0
3:0:0`

But it should go like:

`0:0:1
0:0:2
0:0:3`

PS. I will make it CLS after every output, and it won't just spam on screen.

Comment: `s=60` is an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: `s = 60` assign 60 to `s` in every context, even in an `if`'s condition. To compare, use `x == 60`.

Comment: `if` statements in the code will always result in true. Replace `=` with `==`.

Comment: The `while` statement contains a variable declaration, not a comparison.

Comment: What do you mean by "CLS" in your PS?

Answer (score 1):

Statement `if (s = 60)` first does an assignment `s=60` and then checks if the result of this assignment (which is `60`) is not equal `0`; Hence, this is the same as if you wrote `if(60 != 0)`, which is obviously always true and the if-block is entered (setting `s=0`).

Similarily, `if (m = 60)` is always true, and so `m` will be set to `0` and `h` is the only variable which is increased.

So in statement `cout << h << ":" << m << ":" << s`, `h` will increase, while `m` and `s` are always `0`.

Write `if (s == 60)` and `if (m == 60)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters already pointed out you assign `s = 60` and `m = 60` in your `if` statements instead of comparing if `s` or `m` are equal to `60`.

To avoid such error in the future it helps to get used to put the literal (in this case the `60`) always on the left side of a comparison like `60 == s`. If you accidentally write `60 = s` the compiler will throw an error, because the assignment is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You never compare them you assign

> if (s = 60) {

this will make s 60 and this

> if (m = 60) {

will make m 60 every time and sense m = 60 is true this will run every time and it will increase h by one every time so you should use  ==  to compare them